# Splitting SCXML over multiple xml files

Tags: xml, qt, qt5, scxml, qxmlstreamreader

I am creating different SCXML files which are then used by a Qt application. In order to better structure my state machine, I would like to separate the common part of one machine from the custom state of every other machine. So I thought to split my state machine over 2 files.

Parent file: **parentStateMachine.scxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml"
       version="1.0"
       binding="early"
       xmlns:qt="http://www.qt.io/2015/02/scxml-ext"
       name="MyStatemachine.scxml"
       qt:editorversion="4.2.2"
       datamodel="ecmascript"
       initial="s1"
       xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <state id="init">
        <transition type="external" event="prepare" target="configure"/>
    </state>
    <state id="configure">
        <transition type="external" event="start" target="run"/>
    </state>
    <parallel id="run">
        <!-- include here application specific states-->
        <transition type="external" event="stop" target="end"/>
    </parallel>
    <final id="end">
    </final>
</scxml>
```

application specific: **applicationSpecific1.scxml**

```
<state id="applicationSpecificState1"/>
<state id="applicationSpecificState2"/>
<state id="applicationSpecificState3"/>
```

I have tried including the application specific within the parent one in 2 ways:

1. I tried inserting `<xi:include href="applicationSpecific1.xml"parse="text"/>` instead of the comment.
2. I tried adding `<!DOCTYPE scxml [<!ENTITY innerFile SYSTEM "applicationSpecific1.scxml">]>` right after the `xml` tag and then adding `&innerFile;` instead of the comment.

When I load the documents they are parsed fine but from the behavior I would deduce that it does not take into account whatever is defined in the application specific scxml.

**PS:**
I have found this old unresolved bug report which I hope is already resolved.
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-1088

Comment: I can verify the same behavior with Qt 5.10. The SCXML spec gives an example of how to do this: https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#N11608. But unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be supported by Qt yet.